# fragment inside a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

In my application I am making use of navigation drawer which is in the MainActivity and this navigation drawer has say 5 fragments. I am not maintaining any backstack of these fragments.
Now, the first fragment has one button which when clicked pushes a fragment (which I call an inner fragment). Here, I am maintaining a backstack because I want to get back to the first fragment from the inner fragment.

Now, I have a requirement in which I want to navigate from an activityA to the inner fragment.
Is this possible?
One way that I have thought of is to have the push code inside the first fragments create method (and make this conditional).
But I don't think its an appropriate way. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: navigate from an activityA to the inner fragment/?? what you mean?

Comment: I mean to say that.. I want to navigate from ActivityA to MainActivity's innerfragment (i.e., a fragment thats being pushed by the first fragment)